# Node. JWT авторизация. Сторона клиента

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, handlebars, passport

Стоит пояснить что я *не использую* angular, vue, react  и прочие подобные штуки. При определенном роуте express отправляет клиенту hbs страницу.
Я использую jwt токен+passport для авторизации на сайте, но возник вопрос каким образом я могу отправить этот токен с клиента на сервер. Как я понял, мне нужно запихнуть токен в заголовок запроса, но как это сделать если при не авторизации, сервер отправляет клиенту ошибку `Unauthorized` и какие либо манипуляции с данными на стороне клиента не представляются возможными.

Comment: сервер должен отправлять промежуточный ответ при входе на страницу с параметрами которыми он ждет ответ с кодом 204. эти данные надо так и отправить. Там указанно что в голову что в тело

Comment: спасибо, это и впрямь то, что я искал! Но тут же остается вопрос каким способом получать токен от клиента. Получается на страницах, на которых нужна авторизация, нужно выполнять код, который будет отправлять токен на сервер? мне кажется это довольно муторно, разве нет?

Comment: у вас на сервере должна быть промежуточная проверка. к примеру есть  2 относительных url : ``/account`` и ``/goods``. Ваш middleware должен уметь определять где защищенный url а где нет. Для защищенных url должна быть проверка наличия токена и его проверка на действительность. У меня есть небольшой проект над которым я работал но там система fastify api в роли бэка и next.js в роли фронта. Но фронт может быть совершенно любой.И я не сторонник jwt поэтому использую обычно токен сгенерированный с помощью sha3 так называемой ( Keccak ).

Comment: так как не хватило места допишу тут =)  Отправлять токен нужно при каждом запросе требующем идентификации

Comment: У меня выходит так: При переходе на люблю страницу пользователь паралельно  отправляет post запрос на какой нибудь ../api/auth/token/ там происходит встроенная проверка токена от пасспорта `passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false})` и если токен подходит то пост запрос выполняется. Но как теперь прикрутить ко всем страницам требующим авторизации результат выполнения этого пост запроса?

Comment: а где гарантия что запросы к api будут защищены? Если вы защищаете только сам роутинг а сами запросы не будут проходить проверку то ваша защита станет бесполезной. По поводу проверки доступа к странице... создайте функцию которая будет выполняться ДО отбаботки самой страницы и ее отправки... если проверка токена проходит то отрисовываете запрашиваемую страницу... если нет то выдаете ошибку 403 ну или по желанию роут ставите и тд.